# Issue on VBA changing UK dates to US dates when copy-pasting values in another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

I've a code that opens a recent spreadsheet, copies the data, and pastes it into the main file. There are dates in column E in both files, always in UK format.

However, when pasting the data from the recent spreadsheet to the main one, the dates get transformed into US format, e.g. 02/10/2022 is 02 OCT 2022 with cell value 44836, but it gets pasted as 10/02/2022 as 10 FEB 2022 cell value 44602. It is the whole column that is affected by that.

I've seen other users struggling with that, and tried to format as text, format as date, add new columns, etc., but nothing has fixed it.

I believe the issue is on this step:

```
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyDir & myMostRecentFile
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="PRD"
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    wb.Sheets("D").Range("A70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
```

Some options I tried (without success):

```
Columns("E").Copy
Columns("E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Columns("E").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("E1", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Full code if needed:

```
Sub D_ImportAutoReport()

Dim myFile As String, myRecentFile As String, myMostRecentFile As String
Dim recentDate As Date
Dim MyDir As String
Dim fileExtension As String
Dim fileFilter As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbImp As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Sheets("D").Range("A70:Q337").ClearContents

MyDir = "Q:\TEST\Scheduled Reports\"
fileExtension = "*.csv*"
fileFilter = "PRD*"

myFile = Dir(MyDir & fileFilter & fileExtension)

If myFile <> "" Then
    myRecentFile = myFile
    recentDate = FileDateTime(MyDir & myFile)
        Do While myFile <> ""
            If FileDateTime(MyDir & myFile) > recentDate Then
                myRecentFile = myFile
                recentDate = FileDateTime(MyDir & myFile)
            End If
            myFile = Dir
        Loop
End If

myMostRecentFile = myRecentFile

Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyDir & myMostRecentFile
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="PRD"
    Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    wb.Sheets("D").Range("A70").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it swap months with days for day less or equal to 12 and keep them as strings for day bigger then 12? **Is this your case**? If so, I have a solution to format it as you need. If not, please better describe your situation in relation to what I tried assuming above...

Comment: You're opening text files, so you should specify the `Local:=True` argument for `Workbooks.Open` for it to interpret dates according to your regional settings rather than US settings.

Comment: Adding the Local:=True fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the pasted data looks as I assumed above (and you did not confirm/infirm...), you may use the next function to convert it as you need:

```
Function convertUSStr_DateToUK(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arrConv, arrStrD, i As Long
    ReDim arrConv(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrConv)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(arr(i, 1)), Day(arr(i, 1)), Month(arr(i, 1)))
        Else
            arrStrD = Split(arr(i, 1), "/")
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(arrStrD(2)), CLng(arrStrD(0)), CLng(arrStrD(1)))
        End If
    Next i
    convertUSStr_DateToUK = arrConv
End Function
```

You can use it in the next way:

```
Private Sub testConvertUSStr_DateToUK()
     Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrD
     Const col As String = "B" 'use here your column to convert its Date
     
     Set sh = ActiveSheet
     lastR = sh.Range(col & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     
     arrD = sh.Range(col & 2 & ":" & col & lastR).Value2 'Date is taken as number...
     arrD = convertUSStr_DateToUK(arrD)
     'drop the converted array content and format it appropriately:
     With sh.cells(2, col).Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)
            .Value2 = arrD
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Thanks to FaneDuru for the answer.  I found however that I needed to make the following code tweaks (I cannot provide this as a comment as I do not have sufficient reputation).  I'm not trying to claim this is a different answer.
It's possible my tweaks are inelegant and could be done better as I'm pretty new to VBA, but the code now works for my case where I was pasting data copied from a browser displayed table (with UK format dates) and finding that Excel was treating dates as FaneDuru inidicated above.  That is that when the day value is >12, the date is pasted as Text unchanged, but when the day value is <=12 the text is converted to a Date format assuming that the source text is a US format date (regardless of Windows localisation settings).

I changed the 2nd DateSerial() call in the function (i.e. the Else case where the cell contents are detected as NOT being Numeric being in General text format) because the order used in the call in the answer was (I think) for a US format date.  The OP specified that their source dates (in text) were all in UK format (as was my case also).

```
Function convertUSStr_DateToUK(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arrConv, arrStrD, i As Long
    ReDim arrConv(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrConv)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(arr(i, 1)), Day(arr(i, 1)), Month(arr(i, 1)))
        Else
            arrStrD = Split(arr(i, 1), "/")
            arrConv(i, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(arrStrD(2)), CLng(arrStrD(1)), CLng(arrStrD(0)))
        End If
    Next i
    convertUSStr_DateToUK = arrConv  
End Function
```

I also changed the "With sh.Cells(2, col).Offset(, 0).Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)"  line in the subroutine so that the Offset is (,0) rather than (,1) as I found that in the original code the corrected values were being pasted into the next column (this may have been intentional). This tweak is so that the final output just corrects the dates in-situ.

```
    Private Sub testConvertUSStr_DateToUK()
     Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrD
     Const col As String = "D" 'use here your column to convert its Date
     
     Set sh = ActiveSheet
     lastR = sh.Range(col & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     
     arrD = sh.Range(col & 2 & ":" & col & lastR).Value2 'Date is taken as number...
     arrD = convertUSStr_DateToUK(arrD)
     'drop the converted array content and format it appropriately:
     With sh.Cells(2, col).Offset(, 0).Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)
            .Value2 = arrD
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
     End With
End Sub
```